# what to write in prefix and in environment variable for correct installation

Tags: command-line, software-installation, environment-variables

I am installing linbox library: http://www.linalg.org/developer.html. The installation guide states, that one should install several libraries, including fflas-ffpack library, and then run the script autogen.sh, optionally specifying the installation prefix:

```
cd linbox  
./autogen.sh [--prefix=<prefix>] [options].  
[options] include --with-fflas-ffpack=<fflas-ffpack-prefix>, which, according to the installation guide, is needed only if the package is not installed at a standard location such as /usr or /usr/local. It is also necessary to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to support dynamic linking with the lib directory of any of the packages installed in a nonstandard place in that case.
```

I have installed fflas-ffpack library.

```
~$ sudo dpkg -L fflas-ffpack returns  
/.  
/usr  
/usr/include  
/usr/include/fflas-ffpack  
/usr/include/fflas-ffpack/fflas-ffpack-config.h  
/usr/include/fflas-ffpack/fflas-ffpack-optimise.h  
/usr/bin  
/usr/bin/fflas-ffpack-config  
/usr/share  
/usr/share/doc  
/usr/share/doc/fflas-ffpack  
/usr/share/doc/fflas-ffpack/README  
/usr/share/doc/fflas-ffpack/TODO  
/usr/share/doc/fflas-ffpack/changelog.Debian.gz  
/usr/share/doc/fflas-ffpackcopyright  
/usr/share/doc/fflas-ffpackNEWS.gz  
/usr/share/man  
/usr/share/man/man1  
/usr/share/man/man1/fflas-ffpack-config.1.gz.
```

However when I used command `./autogen.sh`, an error was reported (`ERROR: Fflas-Ffpack not found!`). I am not sure what the problem is and suppose that I should use `--with-fflas-ffpack=<fflas-ffpack-prefix>` option.

I do not know whether I determined the problem correctly and if so what I should write instead of the word "prefix" in the expression `--with-fflas-ffpack=<fflas-ffpack-prefix>`, whether I should write something in place of [--prefix=] and which path I should assign to the variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (`/usr`, `/usr/include` or `/usr/share`).

I would be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: Since you *did* install `fflas-ffpack` in a standard directory, (by using `apt-get`), the error is more likely because of a version mismatch, I suspect. Does the `./configure` script output indicate what version(s) it is checking for?

Comment: Thank you! ./configure stated that it cannot foung the right version, so you are absolutely right about the nature of the problem.